# EF4 to datagrid with a combo box as a column in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, entity-framework-4

I have a list of entities and I need to bind it to a datagrid. One of the properties in the list is a collection and I need to bind that to a combo box within a datagrid. I am new to Windows Forms.

```
var list = (from p in db.persons
               select new person{p.firstname,p.lastname,p.phonenumbers}).tolist()
```

I need phone numbers bound to a combo box column which is like a preferred phone number for the person. A person can change their phone number from their list of provided phone numbers.

How can I track this change in ef4?

please guide me with any articles or examples.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the sample code with ComboBox in the DataGrid here: http://www.gotdotnet.ru/files/download/109/